# php increment operator when pre pending string

Tags: php, increment, post-increment

Im not sure why the following occurs in php

```
<?php

//make the array first

$example = array();
$i = 0;
while($i < 10) {  
  $example[$i++] = $i;
}   
var_dump($example);
//looks good here. As expected
$i = 0;
while ($i < 10) {
  $example[$i] = $i . " " . $example[$i++];
}

var_dump($example);
//this one should contain each of the values again for example
$expected = array(
  "0 0",
  "1 1",
  "2 2",
  //etc
);
```

When doing the same in Java

```
public class append
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array = new String[10];
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
      array[i] =  i++  + "";
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
      array[i] = i + " " + array[i++];
    }

    i = 0;
    while(i < 10) {
      System.out.println (array[i++]);
    }
  }
}
```

It returns correct, The only thing i can think of is operator precedence. Is it because `[` out ranks `++` in PHP and in Java `++` outranks everything ?

Sorry theres a lot of code, thought it would explain better than I would

Comment: Precedence and order of evaluation are two different things. Like C and C++, it looks like PHP does not specify an order of evaluation. http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php : "Operator precedence and associativity only determine how expressions are grouped, they do not specify an order of evaluation. PHP does not (in the general case) specify in which order an expression is evaluated and code that assumes a specific order of evaluation should be avoided, because the behavior can change between versions of PHP or depending on the surrounding code"

Comment: On the other hand, Java does specify an evaluation order http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html : "The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right"

Comment: `[` is not an operator.

Comment: `for` or `foreach` are more appropriate here instead of `while`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i didnt think so but it appears in the chart.

Comment: @milleniumbug i know but the code was made as example code to show the issue. Not a copy and paste of what I'm doing

Comment: @MichaelBurr if you post as an answer I will accept

Comment: @exussum: Oh I see they've documented it weirdly. It is in fact the entire infix `[]` that's the operator.

Comment: The major difference between PHP and Java (other than the PHP being a server sided language) is that PHP is actually a scripting language.